# I can replace a query with java code, is it better?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, optimization

I have to make a count of items.

Is it better to make a select with count so the db(postgreSQL) can execute it fast or to access every single object in java and counting it?

In one way i will need to access the database one more time but in the other i will cycle a lot of objects.

Consider that the application is enterprise so i can have thousands of objects.

I need the best solution to optimize this.

Comment: let the database do the job... most are already optimized for *that* job, also much less data transfer (not always true, I know, but very probable for counting)

Comment: it depends.....

Comment: Too broad of a question you have here. There's no general answer to this, only production profiling over time can show which is preferrable. Not even profiling on your dev, since that's going to have different table statistics, so different execution plans and all that.

Comment: If the object/list/collection your storing your items in doesn't have some sort of `count` or `length` method to retrieve this instantly, then you're probably using the wrong sort of object/list/collection - i.e. you already *should* have that information in memory.

Comment: If you're trying to get a "total" records, as in: `viewing records 1-10 of 10,010` - then, no, don't load all the records in just to count them.  But if you've already loaded them, then no need for a 2nd DB call.

Comment: Also, "thousands" for enterprise grade is rather low. Some have tens of millions. If you're not going to use them for anything other than counting, no use of pulling them over the net to your app server when you can pull a single LONG. If you're concerned about two database roundtrips, just make a query with several result sets, one of which is count and the other is whatever you're actually using.

Answer (score 1):

If you are already fetching all the rows, it may make more sense to simply fetch the max row number from it.

Normally I would let database do the job, but may be in your case it could be simple count from java if it is exactly same query you are firing for fetching all rows and to get count.

If you are using java sql resultset, you can move the cursor to last entry directly and get its row number / count. Hence you don't need to cycle your resultset in Java to just get the total count

```
int size = 0;
try {
    resultSet.last();
    size = resultSet.getRow();
}
catch(Exception ex) {
    return 0;
}
return size;
```

While DB will execute and process queries promptly, there comes a cost of making a connection if not available and using create/prepared statements for better performance. Hence it is very important to understand what your process fitment needs to make it an efficient application.

Comment: He's not asking "*how do I count*". He's asking "*should I count in Java or in SQL*".

Comment: My bad I feel it would be better to not send another DB query here. Also i posted an example as he mentioned of iterating through resultset to get the count ".....but in the other i will cycle a lot of objects". Added a little more info that point

Comment: We don't know if he's fetching all the rows - he's saying he thinks the server can handle it.

Comment: I understand your point.

Answer (score 1):

The comment from @CarlosHeuberger was apt, but all aspects:

- The database can do it faster; has metadata; can go over indices.
- The database caches. (Concurrent and repeated calls.)
- There is less data transfer.
- No need to create java objects, even if they are just belonging to a ResultSet.
- Java code might require more time to read carefully (maintenance).

I do not think the following is the case here, reading the question. But for other people:

- Search the count to insert a new record with id `count + 1` is a huge NO. Unsafe and there exist better mechanisms.

If you do this for *paging* one would not need to load all records on beforehand.

Comment: Regarding paging: I came to think that [marker-based](https://developer.box.com/en/guides/api-calls/pagination/marker-based/) paging is usually better than offset paging, assuming there is a natural criteria to build it.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov indeed, though the effort, required code, is (too) large, one can make a reusable component of it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use some DAO? In hibernate you can use HQL, which is translated to specified SQL syntax. You don't have to strictly couple Java code with one database version, let hibernate do the job. 
Anyway IMO you made mistake with tags, JQuery is not connected to Java, it's JavaScript script.